# Returning to UK after £4000 worth of debt, could I be jailed?

Tags: united-kingdom, debt

I left the UK about 6 months ago to work and hope to go back home to visit family this weekend. However I have accumulated about £4000 of debt through different companies (£700 is the most amount of debt from one indivual company). I have had court officers at my old house looking or me. I plan to go home and sort debt and plan monthly instalments. Do you reckon there will be police/court officers there to meet me in the airport when I land?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Give a call to the companies and find a resolution with them before going home.

Answer (score 7):

You can't be arrested or jailed in the UK for owing money (hasn't been true for about a hundred years). Unless it's a large unpaid fine or a tax bill, and probably not even then. Neither police nor immigration have any interest in who you owe money to.

Comment: While this is true, it's worth noting the edge case. If a person deliberately defrauded a creditor (for example, took on a loan knowing they were about to leave the country and had no intention of paying), that would be a criminal act and could lead to arrest. This is of course different from just owing money. DJClayworth is correct, you can't be arrested or jailed in the UK simply for owing money.